# NativeScript app not running in real device. IOS14 XCODE12

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript

Since i updated xcode to version 12 because of IOS 14 my NativeScript apps don't run on real device but works on the simulator.

i tried this but it didn't work.
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8665

I got this error:
[XCODE error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plYjZ.png)

This is the package.json:

{
"nativescript": {
"id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"tns-android": {
"version": "6.4.1"
},
"tns-ios": {
"version": "6.4.2"
}
},
"description": "App description",
"license": "XXXX",
"repository": "XXXXXX",
"dependencies": {
"nativescript-camera": "^4.5.0",
"nativescript-datetimepicker": "^1.2.2",
"nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.11",
"nativescript-geolocation": "^5.1.0",
"nativescript-imagepicker": "^7.1.0",
"nativescript-phone": "^2.0.0",
"nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.6",
"tns-core-modules": "~6.4.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.0"
},
"gitHead": "42f2a6a9c94eaf9c68d2a41e0daaa1a2544bc28f",
"readme": "NativeScript Application"
}

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the JSC in iOS 14. You’ll have to upgrade to tns-ios 6.5.2 or the new 7.0.0 to have your app reliably start on iOS 14.